# How to zoom to an ILayer?

Tags: arcobjects, zoom

I used `IFeatureLayerDefinition.CreateSelectionLayer()` to create a new `IFeatureLayer` then i cast this one to `ILayer` and set it to the Map, my problem is that i can't zoom programmatically to this `ILayer`, i tried to call `ICommand.ControlsMapFullExtentCommandClass` but it didn't work.

This is my code :

```
public static void myFunction(ITable table_commune, string code_commune)
{

        if(table_commune == null || code_commune == null) return;

        ILayer layer = (ILayer)table_commune;
        IFeatureLayer featureLayer = (IFeatureLayer)layer;

        IFeatureLayerDefinition featureLayerDef = (IFeatureLayerDefinition)featureLayer;

        IFeatureLayer new_featureLayer = featureLayerDef.CreateSelectionLayer("Commune", false, null, "NUM_COMMUNE = " + (code_commune));
        ILayer new_layer = (ILayer)new_featureLayer;

        Map.AddLayer(new_layer);
        Map.ActiveView.Refresh();

        ICommand command = new ControlsMapFullExtentCommandClass();
        command.OnCreate(Map.Object);
        if(command.Enabled) command.OnClick();
}
```

Comment: Can you include the section of code you tried?

Comment: Sorry for that, i added it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first select the layer in the table of contents refrencing this snippet:

[HowTo:  Select a layer in the Table of Contents of ArcMap using ArcObjects](http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/28192)

Then, zoom to the active layer (ILayer) referencing this snippet:

[Zoom to Active Layer in TOC Snippet](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//004900000022000000)